# How to find matches by multiple keys and extract values for matches on two consecutive lines?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a file with following lines

```
key1=value1 AND key2=value2 followed by some other text
key3 {value3} some text key4 - value4 and key5 - value5
```

Is it possible to extract the values 1,3, 4 and 5 and print ? Please note only consider matches where there are all the matches in two consecutive lines. If it makes it any easier I know the keys I'm looking for.

Output ( or something similar )

```
key1 = value1, key3=value3, key4 = value4, key5 = value5
```

Example 1 -

```
abc = 12ty3 AND jfk = 345 followed by some other text
klm {678er} some text plr - 567 and deg - 345
```

Output

```
abc = 12ty3, klm = 678er, plr = 567 , deg = 345
```

Example 2 -

```
xyz-232  abc = 126y3 AND jfk = 567 followed by some other text dre {567x}
klm {rtyyr} some text plr - 444 and deg - 555 some text 345 = uut
```

Output

```
abc = 126y3, klm = rtyyr, plr = 444, deg = 555
```

Comment: And how do you know that these 2 lines should be considered? Based on what pattern?

Comment: @stephanmg based on the keys I'm looking for. consider if all the keys are found in two consecutive lines in the order it is shown.

Comment: And you want that only for lines which are 2 in a row.

Comment: @user2683814, Are those keys always come in order? What are edge cases?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes they do. If we could provide answer to the example in question that would suffice. please note key names are made up. they are all different keys.

Comment: what are key naming conventions in your case? Post a realistic sample

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Updated. please let me know if you more info.

Comment: how do you know what keys are in the second line where there are no `=` signs?

Comment: @karakfa for the second line keys are left side of `{` and `-`. please let me know if you more info. All the keys are single word and separated by space before and after.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Can we do `perl`?

Comment: @karakfa I've added more information. Could you please take a look ?

Comment: Why `xyz = 232`  and `dre = 567x` are not in the output in the last example? What is the key here? How to differentiate a "value" from anything else?

Comment: @KamilCuk in both test cases I'm looking for keys `abc`, `klm`, `rtyyr` & `deg`. so the search should be targeting keys and extracting values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just match it with a proper regex.

For example GNU `sed` (for posixish `sed` just replace ex. `\+` with `\{1,\}`) the following:

```
sed 'N;s/\([^ ]*[ ]\+\)\{0,1\}\([^ =]\+\)[ ]*=[ ]\{0,1\}\([^ ]\+\) [^ ]* \([^ =]\+\)[ ]*=[ ]*\([^ ]\+\)[^\n]*\n\([^ ]\+\) {\([^}]\+\)}.* [^ ]\+ - [^ ]\+ .* \([^ ]\+\) - \([^ ]\+\).*/\2 = \3, \4 = \5, \6 = \7, \8 = \9/' <<EOF
key1=value1 AND key2=value2 followed by some other text
key3 {value3} some text key4 - value4 and key5 - value5
abc = 12ty3 AND jfk = 345 followed by some other text
klm {678er} some text plr - 567 and deg - 345
xyz-232  abc = 126y3 AND jfk = 567 followed by some other text dre {567x}
klm {rtyyr} some text plr - 444 and deg - 555 some text 345 = uut
EOF
```

seems to work and generates the following output:

```
key1 = value1, key2 = value2, key3 = value3, key5 = value5
abc = 12ty3, jfk = 345, klm = 678er, deg = 345
abc = 126y3, jfk = 567, klm = rtyyr, deg = 555
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `grep -o` to extract each occurence on its own line, `sed` to reformat those which need, and `paste` to join them back into one line :

```
grep -Eo '\w+\s*=\s*\w+|\w+\s+\{[^}]+\}|\w+\s+-\s+\w+' | sed -E 's/-/=/;s/\{([^}]+)}/= \1/' | paste -sd ','
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/JUaQD4).

Comment: This assumes that the pattern is static, right? So first line 2 keys, second line 3 keys. Is this true @user2683814?

Comment: @stephanmg no it doesn't, the grep command is extracting every key/value pair that respects one of the three formats outlined in the sample. You can check the updated ideone sample where I added the second input sample to the script's input.

Comment: Thanks Aaron - I've quite a few matches when I use your command. It is matching all the instances of delimiters. Would it be possible to look up searches by key and extract the values ? Also noticed the code is not taking into account whether the matches are in consecutive lines.  I've updated the question to provide other test case.

Comment: If you want to lookup by key you can use `grep -Po "$key\s*[-={]\s*\K\w+"` ([try it here](https://ideone.com/H5n2BL)), but that doesn't check that the matches are all in two consecutive lines. KamilCuk's answer does that though, you should check it out